# How can I use a lambda function in the FindAsync() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to find objects that match a certain requirement. In this case, I want the className attribute of the Course class to be equal to "course". The statement I wanted to use was:

```
Course matchingCourse = collection.FindAsync(x => x.className == "course");
```

The className attribute is not the primary key, so I cannot simply put the key in.

From this I get the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type". I have looked around and I cannot figure out how to solve the issue in this context.

How can I use a lambda to do what I'm trying to do in FindAsync(), or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Where` followed by a `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` or just  pass the predicate to those, unless you need the cache that `Find` gives you. This will call the database each time. `Find` only works on primary keys.

For example:

```
Course matchingCourse = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.className == "course");
```

For Async:

```
Course matchingCourse = await collection.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.className == "course");
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `Find` and `Select` is that Find will first check whether the object that you want has been fetched before since you created the DbContext. Select will always fetch the data from the database.

In fact, Find is used, if you fetched an object, lost the reference to it, and want the fetched object again, not the original.

Usually it is not a good idea to keep the DbContext alive for a long time, so chances are very small that you loose the reference to the fetched object.

Therefore my advice would be to use Select to fetch the item:

(leaving out the async, not part of your problem)

```
var result = collection
    .Where(collectionElement => collectionElement.ClassName == "course")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you really need to get the earlier fetched item, you can use `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<...>()` and do a `Where(...)` on the already fetched objects